# In Typescript, why is JSX.IntrinsicElements not working as documentation describes?

Tags: typescript, jsx

I'm trying to use JSX on the server side, without React. I'm following the typescript docs about JSX [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#intrinsic-elements), and wrote the following in a `.tsx` file.

```
declare namespace JSX {
  interface IntrinsicElements {
    foo: any
  }
}
let elt1 = <foo/>
let elt2 = <bar/>
```

The linked docs say:

> In the above example, `<foo/>` will work fine but `<bar/>` will result in an error ...

But for me, they both result in the same error:

> Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
>   Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [module augmentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). I got the answer from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10859#issuecomment-246496707). Try this:

```
import React from "react";

declare module "react" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      foo: any
    }
  }
}

let elt1 = <foo/>
let elt2 = <bar/>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rys5nn?file=index.tsx)

The reason your code doesn't work is because `JSX.IntrinsicElements` is taken from `@types/react` and redeclaring the namespace won't work. Also you'll notice your code will work if you don't import react ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ugzhq7)). Module augmentation basically extends the `@types/react` types.

Comment: Okay, that helps. I wasn't importing react but both `react` and `@types/react` are in my package.json because I'm using them for client side stuff. Maybe I can find a way to exclude them from my server side builds.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the namespace in a `.tsx` file, try creating a `global.d.ts` file in the `src` folder (or wherever you keep your TS files).

This should serve as your global interfaces file and you shouldn't have that issue anymore.

Comment: That works, but do you know why, or can you point me to where in the typescript docs they explain it?

Comment: Well there is this => https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html which I think is so so... But a better article discussing/explaining declarations in Typescript would be this => https://medium.com/@mikenorth/guide-to-typescript-ambient-declarations-717ef6da6514